# Set treeview.SelectedNode by index (List<Int>)

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I want to set the TreeView.selected node by itterating a int List but I can't figure out how to set the childNodes. I have the following code in my custom control:

```
 private void SetSelectedNode()
    {
        if (MySelectedNodeIndexes == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < MySelectedNodeIndexes.Count; i++)
        {
            this.SelectedNode = this.Nodes[MySelectedNodeIndexes[i]];

        }            
    }
```

This only sets the node but on the first itteration. But the second itteration should set this.SelectedNode.Nodes[first entry in MyselctedNodesIndexes].SelectedNode. and so on.

If MySelectedNodeIndexes contains {2,4,7,1} I want the selected Nodes to be:
this.Nodes[2].nodes[4].nodes[7].nodes[1];

I don't know how to do this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It's hard to make sense of your question since a list of integers doesn't correspond with a TreeNode collection.  Each node in a TreeView has it's own Nodes collection, and so on and so on.  It's not a linear list.

Comment: If MySelectedNodeIndexes contains {2,4,7,1} I want the selected Nodes to be: this.Nodes[2].nodes[4].nodes[7].nodes[1];

Comment: @Jan-WIllem Okay now it's more clear. Put it into the question. Your list actually represent the index at each node level in order to get to the node you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a for loop to find the node base on the input index list. For example:

```
TreeNode GetNodeByIndexPath(TreeView treeView, int[] indexPath)
{
    var nodes = treeView.Nodes;
    TreeNode node = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < indexPath.Length; i++)
    {
        node = nodes[indexPath[i]];
        nodes = node.Nodes;
    }
    return node;
}
```

**Example**

```
var path = new int[] { 1, 1, 1 };
treeView1.SelectedNode = GetNodeByIndexPath(treeView1, path);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm always suprised of the simplicity of a correct answer. To bad I çouldn't figure it out myselve.

Comment: Not bad, no worries, practice makes perfect.